Is there a way to project onto the intersection of a box and a half-space in closed form?
My problem is to project a fixed point $\hat{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ onto the intersection of two convex closed sets, in particular a box and an half-space. Formally, we want to find
$$
\arg\min_y\|\hat{x}-y\|_2^2, \quad\text{with }\: y\in X:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid l\leq x\leq u\}\cap\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid a^Tx\geq b\}
 $$
where $a>0$, $0\leq l<u$ are all given vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $b>0$ a fixed real value. The inequalities are to be intended as element-wise.
I found several iterative methods to project onto $X$ when in general $X$ is the intersection of two closed convex subsets (Dykstra for instance), but I can't figure out a closed form for the projection or some way to project in one step without iterations. It is very easy to project directly into the box or into the half-space separately, but I can hardly see how to properly do that into their intersection.

Relevant: slide 6-12 in Vandenberghe’s EE 236c notes. Shows how to project onto the intersection of a hyperplane and a box.

First project onto the box, and if the result is in the half-space, you're done. Otherwise, the optimal point must be on the boundary of the half-space, so project onto the intersection of the box and hyperplane $a^Tx=b$.

@littleO thanks. It's not really clear to me how  to calculate the lambda when it is said " $P_C(x)=P_{[l,u]}(x-\lambda a)$ where $\lambda$ is the solution of the equation $a^T P_{[l,u]}(x-\lambda a)=b$ ". It doesn't seem to be the trivial $\lambda=\frac{a^Tx-b}{a^T a}$, does this become a subproblem as well or am I missing something?
